# как сделать ссылку типа - site.ru/file.php?id=...&name=...&wons=...&games=... Чтобы потом они выводились на экран?

Tags: php

Ссылка на код:
https://pastebin.com/wHd2pHi2
Пожалуйста,помогите исправить,бьюсь уже 3-й день

Answer (score 1):

Добрый вечер.
И в чём у Вас сложность?

```
$url = 'http://site.ru/file.php?name='.$name.'&amp;games='.$games;
```

Переменную $url подставить в атрибут href тега "a"

Comment: Нужно подставить в href?

Comment: Конечно же. Не понимаю, чем вызвана сложность для Вас.

Comment: То есть,я отдельно пишу $url = 'http://site.ru/file.php?name='.$name.'&amp;games='.$games;
Затем в href подставляю $url.
А как вывести все эти переменные?
session_start();
$name = $_GET['name']
$_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name'];
echo '
<div class="Block">
Nickname: '.print_r($_SESSION['name']).'
</div>';

Comment: Начните, пожалуйста, с изучения основ языка. Тут нет возможности перепечатывать для Вас документацию.